# iOS use of undeclared indentifier after if-else statement

Tags: ios, undeclared-identifier

I have this piece of code which plays my mp3 files on my iphone and it works:

```
if(i == 1) { 
  NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"fart" ofType:@"mp3"];
  player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url] error:NULL];
  [player play];
} else if(i==2) {
  NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"fart6" ofType:@"mp3"];
  player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url] error:NULL];
  [player play];  
} else {
  NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"fart7" ofType:@"mp3"];
  player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url] error:NULL];
  [player play];
}
```

The only lines that are changing is the NSString *url.  When I try to do the below to clean up my code, I get the error of "use of undeclared identifier 'url'".

```
if(i == 1) { 
  NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"fart" ofType:@"mp3"];      
} else if(i==2) {
  NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"fart6" ofType:@"mp3"];        
} else {
  NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"fart7" ofType:@"mp3"];      
}

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url] error:NULL];
[player play];
```

Why does NSURL not understand that the NSString *url is set from the above if-else statements?

Comment: There is yet another opportunity for reducing code repetition, given that resource bundle and type are the same, your if/else block can be setting the file name, from which URL will be generated.

In this case, I would also advise you to use switch/case instead of a bunch of if/else statements.

Comment: Thank you EmptyStack, Jeremy Sherman, and Baglan!  I wish I could give you all check marks for your explanations and solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"The scope the variables is limited to the block they are declared".***

Declare *url* outside before the *if-else* block. You can still optimize your code to be like this.

```
NSString *fileName = @"";
if (i == 1) fileName =  @"fart";
else if (i == 2) fileName =  @"fart6";
else fileName =  @"fart7"; 

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
[player play];
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your solution.. Do you some way to find out when player stops, to release it?? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The scope of the declaration of the `url` variable starts at the point of declaration (when you write `NSURL *url`) and ends at the end of the enclosing block (at the `}`). Each one of those declarations of `url` is in a block (between `{` and `}`), but your attempted use of the declaration is outside any of the blocks that contain a declaration. So, by the time you try to use it, there is no longer a `url` identifier declared within the scope.

To fix it, move the declaration out of the blocks, then assign to the variable from within the blocks:

```
NSString *url = nil;
if(i == 1) { 
  url = …;
} else if(i==2) {
  url = …;
} else {
  url = …;
}

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
    initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url] error:NULL];
[player play];
```

Alternatively:

```
NSString *url = nil;
switch (i) {
case 1: url = …; break;
case 2: url = …; break;
default: url = …; break;
}
```

or even:

```
NSString *url = (1 == i)? val1 : (2 == i)? val2 : valDefault;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C (and other C-bases languages I know), each block has it's own scope so if you declare a variable in that scope, it will not be shared with the containing block but variables from containing block can be seen from the contained block.

A bit vague explanation but here's what you need to do:

```
NSString *url;
if(i == 1) { 
  url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"fart" ofType:@"mp3"];      
} else if(i==2) {
  url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"fart6" ofType:@"mp3"];        
} else {
  url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"fart7" ofType:@"mp3"];      
}

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url] error:NULL];
[player play];
```